# Uniformly distributed conditional probability

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, probability-theory

We have $X \in (0,2)$ and we have $Y \in(0,2X)$, both uniformly distributed. I need to find conditional probabilites.

My try:

We know that uniform distribution has density $\frac{1}{b-a}:$

$$p_X = \frac{1}{2-0} \, \text{for } \, X \in (0,2)$$

$$p_{Y|X=x} = \frac{1}{2X-0} \, \text{for } \, Y \in (0,2X)$$

We know that $0<Y<2X<4 \iff 0<\frac{Y}{2}<X<2$, so:

$$p_{X|Y=y} = \frac{1}{1-Y/2} \, \text{for } \, X\in(Y/2,2)$$

Is the upper correct?

The next thing that I want to ask is:

"Show that $p_Y(y) = \frac{-1}{4}\log(y/4), 0<y<4$"

However I don't know how to show that without integration. Is it possible to do it without integration?

Comment: That $\log$ function is a tell tale sign that integration shall be required somewhere; since the joint density function involves $x^{-1}$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Ok, but if I go by the formula $\frac{p_{x,y}}{p_y} = p_{X|Y=y} \iff p_{y} = \frac{p_{x,y}}{p_{X|Y=y}} = ...$

Comment: @GrahamKemp I should get the same answer right ?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Or even if we just look at the uniform distribution density function formula, which is $\frac{1}{b-a}$ it doesn't make sense that a log is there

Comment: No.  Or rather, the formula would work *if* you knew the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$, which you do not. $X\mid Y\sim\mathcal U(Y/2,2)$ is **not** entailed by $Y\mid X\sim\mathcal U(0,2X)$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Ok, so then I only know $p_{Y|X}$, so if I use that with $p_X$ to get $p_{X,Y} = p_X\cdot p_{Y|X} = \frac{1}{4x}$, but if I integrate that $\int_0^y\frac{1}{4x}$, the integral does not converge.

Comment: Those are not the correct bounds.  The joint support is $0<y/2<x<2$, so when integrating over $x$...

Comment: $\int_{y/2}^{2}\frac{1}{4x} = \frac{1}{4}(\log(2) - \log(y/2)) = \frac{1}{4}\log(4/y)$, which is not correct @GrahamKemp

Comment: It is correct, since: $\log(4/y)=-\log(y/4)$ .

Comment: @GrahamKemp I see, I get it now, $\frac{1}{4}\log((y/4)^{-1}) = -\frac{1}{4}...$

Comment: @VLC did the question ask you for $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ or is that something you were just trying to figure out on your own?

Comment: @MathLover I was just trying to figure that out on my own, since I wanted to use the formula $p_{X|Y} =p_{X,Y}/p_{Y} $

Answer (score 1):

For the last part: I guess that $Y$ is not uniformly distributed, maybe $Y|X$, in this case

$$\begin{align*}
F_Y(c)&=\Pr [Y\leqslant c]\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\Pr [Y\leqslant c|X=t]F_X(dt)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\mathbf{1}_{[0,2t]}(c)\frac{c}{2t}+\mathbf{1}_{(2t,\infty )}(c)\right)\mathbf{1}_{[0,2]}(t)\frac1{2}\,d t\\
&=\frac{c}{4}\mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty )}(c)\int_{[c/2,2]}\frac1{t}\,d t+\frac1{2}\int_{[0,\min\{c/2,2\}]}\,d t\\
&=\frac{c}{4}\log \left(\frac{4}{c}\right)\mathbf{1}_{(0,4]}(c)+\min\left\{\frac{c}{4},1\right\}\mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty )}(c)
\end{align*}$$

Therefore, almost everywhere, we have that

$$
f_Y(c)=\frac14\left(\log \left(\frac{4}{c}\right)-1\right)\mathbf{1}_{(0,4]}(c)+\frac1{4}\mathbf{1}_{(0,4]}(c)=\frac1{4}\log \left(\frac{4}{c}\right)\mathbf{1}_{(0,4]}(c)
$$